# Do double group by to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Dataframe:**

```
STUD_ID   CLASS   GRADE  CATEGORY
1         'Sci'    2    'Alpha'
2         'Sci'    7    undefined
3         'Sci'    9    'Alpha'
4         'Sci'    NaN  'Alpha'
5         'Sci'    9    'Alpha'
6         'math'   9    undefined
7         'eng'    8    'Gamma'
8         'eng'    5    'Gamma'
9         'eng'    3    undefined
10        'Art'    3    'Lambda'
11        'Art'    8    'Lambda'
12        'Art'    5    undefined
13        'Art'    1    undefined
14        'Art'    NaN  undefined
```

I am looking forward to decide if the student category 'undefined' is actually the other-category that is present in that specific class. To know this, it should check if the grade of the 'undefined' category student is between the min-max of the other-category in that class.

**E.g.** Student in row 2 has 'undefined category': The category should change to 'Alpha' since its grade 7 falls between the 'Alpha' min and max grades (2 and 9). 'Alpha' is the other-category of the class 'Sci'

**E.g.** Opposite case, student in row 9. Its category should **not** change to 'Gamma' because its grade 3 falls outside the grade-range of the 'Gamma' (5 - 8). 'Gamma' is the other-category for the class 'eng'

**E.g.** In row 14, the 'undefined' should not change as np.NaN is not comparable.

**E.g.** In row 6, 'undefined' should not change as there are no other 
categories.

**Result**

```
STUD_ID   CLASS   GRADE  CATEGORY
1         'Sci'    2    'Alpha'
2         'Sci'    7    'Alpha' *
3         'Sci'    9    'Alpha'
4         'Sci'    NaN  'Alpha'
5         'Sci'    9    'Alpha'
6         'math'   9    undefined
7         'eng'    8    'Gamma'
8         'eng'    5    'Gamma'
9         'eng'    3    undefined
10        'Art'    3    'Lambda'
11        'Art'    8    'Lambda'
12        'Art'    5    'Lambda' *
13        'Art'    1    undefined
14        'Art'    NaN  undefined
```

For the first undefined. How can I access the group of grades of 'Alpha' after I accessed the group 'Science'?

I know this is possible to access the current class group

```
df.loc[df['CATEGORY'] == 'undefined', 'CATEGORY'] = df.groupby('CLASS')...
```

If something like below was possible to access both CLASS and CATEGORY (other than 'undefined'), it'd be great.

```
func = lambda series : ...get min and max of series...

df.loc[df['CATEGORY'] == 'undefined', 'CATEGORY'] = df.groupby('CLASS').groupby('CATEGORY').where('CATEGORY'!='undefined').transform(func)..
```

How to do this?
An answer that creates helper step columns would also work.

Comment: `df.groupby(['CLASS', 'CATEGORY'])`?

Comment: @HS-nebula Would you please provide a more elaborate answer?

Comment: Would you like show us what did you try  ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen I tried multiple things. I started with ```df.groupby(['CLASS', 'CATEGORY'])``` but what is passing to the transform function doesn't make much sense to me, it's not a series. I also tried what I wrote in the post but that evidently doesn't work. Also ```df.loc[df['CATEGORY'] == 'undefined', 'CATEGORY'] = df.groupby('CLASS')[df.groupby('CLASS').CATEGORY!='undefined'].transform(func)``` and didn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the following works for you:

1. Get the GRADE boundary for each group

   ```
   min_grade = df.groupby('CLASS').GRADE.transform('min')
   max_grade = df.groupby('CLASS').GRADE.transform('max')
   ```
2. find the default category to replace 'undefined' if qualified. below line retrieves the first element in the same group which is not 'undefined' if existing, otherwise 'undefined'

   **UPDATE:** previous code works on Pandas-0.17.1/python-2.7.2, but yields ***ValueError*** on Pandas-0.24.1/Python-3.7.2. Below line was tested on Pandas-0.24.1:

   ```
   default_cat = df.groupby('CLASS').CATEGORY.transform(
       lambda x: x[x!='undefined'].iat[0] if x[x!='undefined'].size > 0 else 'undefined' 
   )
   ```

   Another way to calculate default_cat:

   ```
   default_cat = df.assign(
           cat=df.CATEGORY.replace({'undefined': np.nan})
       ) \
       .groupby('CLASS').cat.transform('first') \
       .fillna('undefined')
   ```
3. Get the new CATEGORY:

   ```
   df['new_cat'] = df.CATEGORY.mask(
       df.CATEGORY.eq('undefined') & df.GRADE.gt(min_grade) & df.GRADE.lt(max_grade)
     , default_cat
   )
   print(df)
   #    STUD_ID CLASS  GRADE   CATEGORY    new_cat
   #0         1   Sci      2      Alpha      Alpha
   #1         2   Sci      7  undefined      Alpha
   #2         3   Sci      9      Alpha      Alpha
   #3         4   Sci    NaN      Alpha      Alpha
   #4         5   Sci      9      Alpha      Alpha
   #5         6  math      9  undefined  undefined
   #6         7   eng      8      Gamma      Gamma
   #7         8   eng      5      Gamma      Gamma
   #8         9   eng      3  undefined  undefined
   #9        10   Art      3     Lambda     Lambda
   #10       11   Art      8     Lambda     Lambda
   #11       12   Art      5  undefined     Lambda
   #12       13   Art      1  undefined  undefined
   #13       14   Art    NaN  undefined  undefined
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Just a question about your step 3. When you do df.GRADE.gt(min_grade), How are you able to compare a grade value (integer) with min_grade (groupbyObject)? They are different objects and different shapes too. ?

Comment: @Kaisar, the return from Series.groupby(..).transform(..) is not a GroupBy object, it's a Series with the same size as the original Series, but rows in the same group filled with the aggregated values. To test this, you can specify it to a column, i.e. `df['min_grade'] = df.groupby('CLASS').GRADE.transform('min')` and see what's in min_grade. This is one of the very useful common patterns in the Pandas programming. you can check more on the official doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation